# Bash - appending options to a defined function in an if statement?

Tags: bash, function, if-statement, append

I've written a short script to undertake a task for a project I'm working on. The jist is its two functions with the options preconfigued and an if statement setting which way to go. However, there's potentially more variables that I'd need to account for in this, I figured I can do this adding another parameter. However what I haven't figured is the extra functions I'd need to configure

So the formula looks a little like this:

```
    function1 () {
       foo $1 $2 -etc -etc -etc} 
    function2 () {
       foo $1 $2 -cte -cte -cte}
    if [ X = Y ] 
    then $(function1 $1 $2)
    else $(function2 $1 $2)
```

I could simply expand this by defining more functions, however as the additional formulas are likely to be the same, though with one or two options added on, what I'm wondering is if, instead of writing out multiple functions, its possible to simply append options onton the previous function during the if statment.

I have no idea how this should be, but for demonstrative sake let's say something like this:

```
if [ X = Y ] && [ Y = Z ]
then $(function1 $1 $2 '--optionA')
else $(function1 $1 $2)
```

EDIT: Here's my code:

```
function wpull_init {
        wpull $1 --warc-file "$ARCHIVELOC/$2/$2" --warc-cdx \
        --warc-header="Operator:$ARCHIVEOPERATOR" \
        --output-file $ARCHIVELOC/$2/$2.log --delete-after --database $ARCHIVELOC/$2/$2.db \
        --convert-links --backup-converted -r -l inf --escaped-fragment --strip-session-id\
        --restrict-file-names=windows \
        --span-hosts-allow linked-pages,page-requisites --page-requisites --sitemaps \
        --reject-regex "/login\.php" --no-check-certificate --no-robots \
        --retry-connrefused --retry-dns-error --wait 1 --waitretry 600 --random-wait \
        --timeout 60 --session-timeout 10800 --tries 3 \
        --limit-rate 2000 --concurrent 5 \
        --user-agent "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.20.25 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.4 Safari/533.20.27" \
        --quiet
        }
function warc-setup {
 if [[ -f $ARCHIVELOC/$2/$2.warc.gz ]];
  then echo "$2.warc.gz exists, running append" && sleep 2 && wpull_init $1 $2 '--warc-append'
  else echo "No file exists, ensuring directory exists for files" && mkdir -p "$ARCHIVELOC/$2" && sleep 2 && echo "Starting up wpull_init" && sleep 2 && wpull_init $1 $2
  fi}
warc-setup $1 $2
```

what I'd be looking to do is add an --warc-append option into the original wpull_init function at the if formula stage.

Comment: Why are there `$( )`? You want to execute _the output_ of `foo`? You want to `shift` two first arguments and then use `"$@"` to forward the rest of arguments?

Comment: I don't want to execute the output of foo, Foo is giving me the output. I used $( ) because that's what got it to work for me, at least? I don't know if I want to use shift or use $@, I don't think so? Ideally, I'd like to accomplish what I described above - I'm fairly new to this so please bear with me.

Comment: Then just `then function1 $1 $2 '--optionA'`. Why the `$()`?

Comment: To get the question clear, you need a function, which can behave in different ways w.r.t the number of arguments passed?

Comment: function1 $1 $2 worked without $() as you say, however the 'optionA' bit didn't. And essentially yes Ankush or more precisely I'm looking to be able to add arguements to the command within the function.

Comment: for KamilCuk's answer did you try adding an extra variable $3 in function to place that third extra `--optionA` ? I guess you are not capturing the 3rd argument (`--optionA`) in your function and that's why it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around this by scraping the multiple functions and simply appending into one function through variables with an if statements. Though I've since progressed to GetOpts options.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like trying to build your command before executing.

```
function foo_call {
    CALL=$(echo "foo $1 $2 $3 $4")
    $($CALL)
}

if [ X = Y ] && [ Y = Z ]
then 
    function1 "arg_1" "arg_2" "--optionA"
else 
    function1 "arg_1" "arg_2"
fi
```

Here for the 2nd case $3 and $4 will be empty. So the variable CALL will store `foo arg_1 arg_2` and in  the first case it will store `foo arg_1 arg_2 --optionA`.

Comment: you can remove storing in external variable and just directly call `foo $1 $2 $3 $4`; that's just to help you debug, where you call echo CALL and see how its resolved.